# Query to select multiple records from same column with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am trying to get records from same column. I want to get the farm codes from two IDs, I tried following with help of CodeIgniter documentation but it doesn't work.

```
        $this->db->select('fa_code');
        $this->db->where('fa_id', $by);
        $this->db->where('fa_id', $from);
        $res=$this->db->get('tukai_farms')->result();
```

What is wrong? Don't we use AND with same field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare from where you want to get 'fa_code' then declare the conditions you have:

This is the correct way:

```
public function selectFaCode(){
        $by = 1;
        $from = 2;
        $query = $this->db->select('fa_code')
                            ->from('tukai_farms')
                            ->where('fa_id', $by)
                            ->or_where('fa_id', $from) //Remember that you are declaring the same condition ! Remove this to keep the first where or change the column name if you want to get items from table where the condition is another column.
                            ->get()
                            ->result();

        foreach($query as $row){
            echo $row->fa_code;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as **anant** said, you should use:

```
$this->db->where('fa_id', $by);
$this->db->or_where('fa_id', $from);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple records from same column with this query

```
$value = array($by, $from);
$this->db->where_in('fa_id', $value);
```